# Where can I to find a Thermodynamic Online Course?

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for an online thermodynamics course at the same level as the physics course professional circle.

I mean, a course at the same level as books: **Thermal physic (Schroeder)** or **Thermodynamics and an introduction to thermostatics (Called)**

Comment: Hi Everson Gomes. Welcome to Phys.SE. Note that res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE.